# Fixed effects model and diagnostic

Tags: panel-data, stata, fixed-effects-model

I try to estimate fixed effects model in Stata and I have some problems with interpretation of my results.

My panel data consists of 700 observations. Five variables have significant impact on dependent variable.

What are the desirable values for:
a) R-squared: within, between, overall
b) corr(u_i, Xb)
c) rho?

Could someone help me and give some explanations? I read a lot of presentations or Stata documentation but the examples of fe models which I found have very different parameters.
I enclosed two links: https://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Panel101.pdf
http://www.svt.ntnu.no/iss/Arild.Blekesaune/SOS8515-filer/Panel_Lab2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

a/ One cannot answer this question without more details on your research design. Having a high $R^2$ seems quite important to make predictions after you did the regressions. But for other research (when one is interested on the marginal impact of a variable, which is mostly what is done in economics research for instance), it is quite possible to find regressions with low $R^2$.

b/ and c/ which Stata command do you use ?